# Google plus: Share links, video, picture to google plus. Not working?

Tags: android, google-plus

I'm currently trying to create an app to share links, pictures or video to Google Plus. I've seen the documentation on sharing from Google Plus developer here: [Sharing to G+ from your app](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share/)

And realised that the part of the code:

```
      Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(this)
```

where my IDE could not resolve PlusShare as it was deprecated as described here: [Plus API deprecation notes.](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/api-deprecation)

Could anyone post a way around as I could not find any example codes on how to share to G+ without using the deprecated code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to programmatically post to the google+ wall/stream. You can only make a GET request for google data.

Comment: thanks for the reply! I've searched and read and could not manage to do any type of sharing to g+. guess ill just stick to just logging in to g+ only